# Как реализован обмен Station-AP-Station

Tags: wifi

Здравствуйте!

Возник весьма интересный вопрос. На фоне того, что во всей документации по Wi-Fi ни слова не сказано о передаче данных от конечной точки до конечной точки, решили протестировать сами. Результатов особенных это нам не принесло, поэтому меня понесло к вам.

Итак, всем известно, что (предположим, что канал свободен) перед передачей данных, станция ожидает DIFS время, слушая канал, если ничего в канале в этот промежуток не было, она начинает отсчет случайного времени t(backoff). Только после этого мы имеем возможность отправлять данные. Кроме того, чтобы иметь преимущество перед остальными, имеется время ожидания SIFS, которое выдерживается перед передачей от точки доступа к станции сообщения ACK, подтверждающего прием.

Далее следует нигде не описанная часть, полученная опытным путем:

Но, перед передачей принятого в буфер точки доступа фрейма получателю, точка доступа снова выполняет DIFS+t(backoff), что выставляет ее вровень с обычными пользователями и не дает никакого преимущества. Соответственно, если каждый раз t(backoff) точки доступа будет больше любой из передающих станций, она будет потихоньку заполнять свой буфер, а отдавать данных не будет совсем. Что по-нашему мнению является не совсем удачным решением, ведь память конечна, а в худшем случае сеть вообще может перестать передавать данные. С точки зрения логики, не лучше было бы использовать SIFS перед отправкой фрейма к конечной станции?

Собственно вопрос, правы ли мы в рассуждениях и тестах? Если нет, прошу подтвердить литературой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Infrastructure Mode (с AP) используется Point Coordination Function (PCF). См. IEEE 802.11-2007, раздел 9.1.2 [1].

1. http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2007.pdf

Comment: Он может использоваться, но по сути не используется, не говоря уже о > This access method uses a PCТ.е. вывод какой, используя только точку доступа и N клиентов, она будет выступать полностью равнозначной с ними, а значит используя баг в прошивке  (выбор наименьшего t(backoff)) можно повалить сеть?Кроме того, есть второй случай, когда один клиент, получает доступ к Интернету посредством ТД. Имея t(backoff) меньше, чем у точки, он сможет отправлять пакеты, а точка вернуть ему ничего не сможет.

Answer (score 0):

Может я ошибаюсь, но мне кажется что любое сетевое устройство имеет некоторое время для заполнения буфера. И если буфер не был заполнен за определенный промежуток времени, то передается то, что было накоплено ранее. То есть данные в буфере не могут висеть бесконечно, ожидая когда буфер полностью заполнится.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю о чем вы. Видимо, вы не поняли вопроса. Имеется ввиду буфер кадров (фреймов) и "искусственное" заполнение буфера точки доступа в ситуации, когда ее t(backoff) всегда больше чем у подключенных к ней станций.